# Count the number of column for each rows of a pandas where a condition holds

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe as follow:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'w1':[0,1,0],'w2':[5,8,0],'w3':[0,0,0],'w4' :[5,1,0], 'w5' : [7,1,0],'condition' : [5,1,0]})
```

[image]

I need to have a column that for each row,counts the number of columns( columns other than "condition") which their values are equal to "condition".
The final output should look like bellow:

[image]

I don't want to write a for loop.

As a solution,I wanted to replace the values which are equal to the "condition" with 1 and others with 0 by `np.where` as bellow, and then sums the 1s of each row, which was not helpful:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(np.where(data.loc[:,data.columns != 'condition'] == data['condition'], 1, 0), columns = data.columns)
```

That was just an idea (I mean replacing the values with 1 and 0) but any pythonic solution isappreciated.

Comment: Why use 0/1 instead of actual booleans?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compare all columns without last by column `condition` with [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and count `True`s by `sum`:

```
data['new'] = data.iloc[:, :-1].eq(data['condition'], axis=0).sum(axis=1)
```

Another idea is compare all columns with remove `condition` col:

```
data['new'] = data.drop('condition', axis=1).eq(data['condition'], axis=0).sum(axis=1)
```

Thank you for comment @Sayandip Dutta, your idea is compare all columns and remove `1`:

```
data['new'] = data.eq(data['condition'], axis=0).sum(axis=1).sub(1)
```

---

```
print (data)
   w1  w2  w3  w4  w5  condition  new
0   0   5   0   5   7          5    2
1   1   8   0   1   1          1    3
2   0   0   0   0   0          0    5
```